# Do experience gain items on your pet affect your character in Torchlight?

Tags: torchlight

In Torchlight there are wearable rings that boost experience gain by a percentage. If I equip my pet with one of these rings, will this increase the experience gain of my player?

Comment: I don't *think* so. I know that if you give your pet +Magic Find items, they will benefit from the magic find only when they kill things (as opposed to you killing them. Your pet has magic find = to your magic find + any magic find items worn by the pet.

Comment: So your magic find affects your pets? The same mechanic would be useless with experience gain but because it's implemented there's a chance they've implemented something experience related.

Comment: exactly. But the way it would work is, if you have a +3% xp ring, and your pet has a +2% xp ring, you would get 103% XP, and your pet would get 105% (all of your xp%, + it's own). However, since pets don't accrue experience, this is irrelevant.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer: Until anyone can prove you wrong that sounds like an answer to me. The thing is it's difficult to test with 2% and 3%. I can't figure it out myself but I'm more convinced that your point about Magic Find applies to experience gain as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is unlikely that your pet's +%xp affects your own.

Looking at the similar stat of +% magic find, I know that if you give your pet +Magic Find items, they will benefit from the magic find only when they kill things (as opposed to you killing them. Your pet has magic find = to your magic find + any magic find items worn by the pet.

But the way this concept would work for XP is, if you have a +3% xp ring, and your pet has a +2% xp ring, you would get 103% XP, and your pet would get 105% (all of your xp%, + it's own). However, since pets don't accrue experience, this is irrelevant.

Comment: I will go through the effort of testing this when I feel like grinding Torchlight again. In the meantime thanks for your input :)

Answer (score 3):

There was a change in [Patch 1.2](http://store.steampowered.com/news/?feed=steam_updates&appids=41500) that sheds some light on this:

> - Magic find takes the max value between you and your pet when pets or pet minions make a kill.

If your pet's trinkets give a total 2% magic find boost, and your own equipment has a total 3% magic find boost, then you will only receive a 3% find rate boost.

I think the meaning of the change is that pre-patch pets and minions would have had their own drop rate that applied whenever they made a kill. The change simplifies the situation, so you don't need to have drop rate boosts for yourself and your pet.

However, it isn't clear if this applies to experience as well.

Comment: If it applied to experience, experience gain would only be maximal if my pet made the kill, and even then it would only apply to my pet. I'm more interested in my character.